# Should I redefine a pandas dataframe with every function?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

From experience, some pandas functions require that I redefine the dataframe if I intend to use them, otherwise they won't return a copy by default. For example: `df.drop("ColA", axis=1)` will not actually drop the column, but I need to implement it by `df = df.drop("ColA", axis=1)` or by `df.drop("ColA", axis=1, inplace=True)` if I need to modify the dataframe.

This seems to be the case with some other pandas functions. Therefore, what I usually do is redefine a dataframe for every function so that I can ensure it is modified. For example:

```
df = df.set_index("id")
df = df.sort_values(by="Date")
df["B"] = df["B"].fillna(-1)
df = df.reset_index(drop = True)
df["ColA"] = df["ColA"].astype(str)
```

I know some of these functions do not require to define the dataframe, but I just do it to make sure the changes are applied. My question is if there is a way to know which functions require redefining the dataframe and which don't need it, and also if there is any computational difference between using `df = df.set_index("id")` and `df.set_index("id")` if they have the same output.

Also is there a difference between `df["B"] = df["B"].fillna(-1)` and `df = df["B"].fillna(-1)`?

Answer (score 1):

> My question is if there is a way to know which functions require redefining the dataframe and which don't need it

It's called the manual.

- [`set_index()`](http://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html#pandas.DataFrame.set_index) has an `inplace=True` parameter; if that's set, you won't need to reassigned.
- [`sort_values()`](http://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html#pandas.DataFrame.sort_values) has that too.
- [`fillna()`](http://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.fillna.html#pandas.Series.fillna) has that too.
- [`reset_index()`](http://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html#pandas.DataFrame.reset_index) has that too.
- [`astype()`](http://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.astype.html#pandas.Series.astype) has `copy=True` by default, but heed the warning setting it to False:

  > "be very careful setting copy=False as changes to values then may propagate to other pandas objects"

> if there is any computational difference between

Yes – if Pandas is able to make the changes in-place, it won't need to copy the series or dataframe, which could be a significant time and memory expense with large dataframes.

> Also is there a difference between `df["B"] = df["B"].fillna(-1)` and `df = df["B"].fillna(-1)`?

Yes, there is. The first reassigns a series into a dataframe, the other just assigns the single series into the (now misnamed) name `df`

Answer (score 1):

In pandas github is long discussion about this, check [this](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/16529).

I also agree the best dont use `inplace`, because confused and not sure how/when it save memory.

> Should I redefine a pandas dataframe with every function?

I think yes, maybe if use large DataFrames here should be exceptions, [link](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/16529#issuecomment-568046026).

There is always list of methods with [`inplace parameter`](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/16529#issuecomment-443783295).

> Also is there a difference between df["B"] = df["B"].fillna(-1) and df = df["B"].fillna(-1)

If use `df["B"] = df["B"].fillna(-1)` it reassign column `B` `(Series)` back with replaced missing values to `-1`.

If use `df = df["B"].fillna(-1)` it return `Series` with replaced values, but it is reassigned to `df`, so original DataFrame is overwitten by this replaced Series.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a solution for this. Some methods work inplace by default and some others return a copy of the df and you need to reassign the df as you usually do. The best option is to check the docs (for the inplace parameter) everytime you want to use some method and you will learn by practice, at least the most common ones, like sorting, reseting index, etc